# Command to run bash that restart vscode?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, visual-studio-code

I'm creating a script then is possible to upgrade flutter to flutter web changing the channel, but my ask is does exist any command to run in a bash file, that I can restart VS Code? Because before I run the script appears "You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings."

Comment: Is VS Code running on Linux or Windows?

Comment: I'm using linux.